# How to play an animation behind a login box?

Tags: html, css, authentication, css-animations

I want to run my animation effect in the background, but it's running it over my login box. My question is what needs to be changed in my login box parent element for the animation to be played behind it?

[image: Image Of Web page.]

```
section {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(5, 189, 230, 0.922), #000);
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

section span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(15.25vw - 6px);
  height: calc(15.25vw - 2px);
  background: #181818;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

}
section .login-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

I want to know what type of correction needs to be made in this CSS section to fix the animation.

Comment: Please update your question to use the live code sandbox here.

Comment: We need to see your html code as well. Please put all the necessary code and use Stack Overflow's code sandbox.

Comment: This should help you put runnable code into your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example